# Which is the strongest declaration in CSS based on ID or class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here I'm using one ID(#mybox) and class(.box) but both are having the same declaration. moreover here working the background color only with ID. apart from the i know only difference between the ID and class but here as comparison with ID and class.it's working with ID what is difference.and in this case what is  strongest in both.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    #mybox{background-color: red;} 
    .box{background-color:yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybox" class="box">
        boxes block
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called CSS Specificity.

ID has infinitely more specificity than class.

You can learn more here: https://web.dev/learn/css/specificity/
And a little bit more fun resource https://cssspecificity.com/

Answer (score 1):

ID wins. Only with !important declaration would the class get the preference.

```
#mybox{background-color: red;} 
.box{background-color:yellow !important;}
/* yellow */
```

**Note:** @owenizedd correctly pointed out !important should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Important is a bad practice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity  and you should avoid it `!important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets`

Comment: @owenizedd That is correct. but that was not the point. It was just to show when it is possible to use the class definition over the id definition.

Comment: Yep, my point also is not for countering your post, more to giving extra note about this would be a great IMO.

Comment: @owenizedd just a comment: If u would _always_ use important it wouldn´t break the cascading nature xD just kidding

Comment: @johnSmith Good to know ;-)